# VBA Multiple value find and replace but also highlight replaced cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that finds and replaces values in one sheet from a list in another sheet. However, I need this code to also highlight the cell, or flag it in some way so that it can be reviewed manually later. Any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
Sub ReplaceValues()
Dim FandR As Worksheet
Dim PDH As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, rngR As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim rngReplacement
Dim c As Range
Dim curVal As String

Set FandR = Sheets("Find and Replace")
Set PDH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Paste Data here")
i = PDH.Rows.Count
With PDH
Set rng = .Range("E1", .Range("E" & i).End(xlUp))
End With

With FandR
    Set rngR = FandR.Range("H")

End With


For Each c In rngR
    curVal = c.Value
    c.Interior.Color = vbYellow

    With rng
        .Replace curVal, c.Offset(0, 1).Value, xlWhole, , True

    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not set the interior color on the target cell just like you're doing on the source cell?

Comment: Not your question, but you don't need `With FandR` if you are going to use `Set rngR = FandR.Range("H")`

Comment: Thank you for the correction Cybernetic.nomad. StoneGiant, if I do that, it does nothing.

Comment: Are worksheets FandR and PDH in the same workbook? Is this code in the ActiveWorkbook? Do you want to highlight the cells to which you are referring to with c.Offset(0, 1)? The 'i' variable is used only one time in the 'Set rng' line, so it is pretty useless.

Comment: the i variable is useless agreed. All these are in the same, active, workbook. FandR has a list of values to search for in column H and in column I values to replace with. The code searches for the H values in column E of sheet PDH and replaces it with FandR!I:I values. However, when the values are replaced, I would also like it to highlight or flag the replaced value in some way. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I figured it out, the replace function has an inbuilt replaceformat function. However, this is a T/F function and the replace format must defined using with function.

Comment: With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With